# Can a square number be expressed as sum of squares of two other members.?

Tags: square-numbers, sums-of-squares, pythagorean-triples

Is there any theorem to tell if square of a number can be expressed as sum of squares of two other distinct numbers.

I have one such set. ${5, 4, 3}$

$5^2 = 4^2 + 3^2$

Given a number $n$ how to find if the above conditions satisfy ?

Comment: is there some sort of recent contest going on, possibly in programming? This question has been repeated by different people for several days

Comment: Does $7^2=7^2+0^2$ count?

Comment: @Element118 No the numbers should be distinct

Comment: @WillJagy This is not the entire question.  This is just a small part of the question.

Comment: @Element118 "other distinct" I think implies "other than this square."

Comment: So how much are you going to win if we give away secrets about famous trios of numbers named after Greek philosophers who were averse to beans? (And how do we get our cut?)

Comment: @RobArthan, not as widely known, the playwright Aeschylus died when an eagle dropped a tortoise on his head. It's in Pliny the Elder. Book 10, Chapter 3, if the link does not quite work.  http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Plin.+Nat.+10.3&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0137

Comment: The question has been asked frequently lately. A search will find the answer, possibly in a comment.

Comment: @WillJagy: did Aeschylus contribute anything to mathematics? (Other than the eagle/tortoise/death statistic)?

Comment: @RobArthan, he did write The Libation Bearers. That's got to count for something. How often do you get to use the word libation?

Comment: @WillJagy: far too often, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the concept of Pythagorean Triples. for:

$$a^2+b^2=c^2$$

you can use the following values for a,b and c where m and n are any two positive integers such that $m>n$:

$$a^2=m^2-n^2 \; and \; b=2mn\; and \; c^2=m^2+n^2 $$

Here is a sample:

[image]

You can read more about the subject in [wiki-Pythagorean_triple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple) and for a better method to generate the numbers in here: [A Direct Method To Generate Pythagorean Triples](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1201/1201.2145.pdf) .

Answer (score 0):

These sets are called pythagorean triplets for obvious reasons.  If {x, y, z} are p. triplets so are any {nx, ny, nz}.  If m is odd there's a way to construct a triplet that I'm holding off on sharing but I'll tell you two of the terms are consecutive.